# Call a Javascript Function with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions in Javascript:

```
function getWindowWidth(){
var x = 0;
if (self.innerHeight){
x = self.innerWidth;
}else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight){
x = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}else if (document.body){
x = document.body.clientWidth;
}return x;
}function getWindowHeight(){
var y = 0;
if (self.innerHeight){
y = self.innerHeight;
}else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight){
y = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}else if (document.body){
y = document.body.clientHeight;
}
```

These appear to set the height and width of the document window, based on the size of the window? I could be wrong here....

What I have done is embeded a toolbar above this document, this toolbar can be hidden or shown at various points.

I need the above function to be called when I use the following jQuery,

```
$("#Main").animate({top: "89px"}, 200);
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: The two functions you posted don't have any effect, they just get some values, calling them wouldn't have any effect unless you're feeding the result to something else.

Comment: Your right, more info required to answer this questions. Above function 'gets' the values required to set height & width but need to find function that sets the height & width first.

Answer (score 2):

[`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) takes a callback function.

```
$("#Main").animate({top: "89px"}, 200, function() {
    getWindowWidth(); 
    getWindowHeight(); });
```

Comment: Which this is correct, it doesn't really address the problem, look at the functions...what are you doing with their return values?  Currently this is just wasting CPU cycles at the animation...